# Twitter API integration problem in iphone

Tags: iphone, mgtwitterengine

I am integrating this API in twitter.

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/twitter-api-iphone/

but when I am running it with my application I am seeing an message

" TWoah there!

This page is no longer valid. It looks like someone already used the token information you provided. Please return to the site that sent you to this page and try again ... it was probably an honest mistake ".

I have given right kOAuthConsumerKey and kOAuthConsumerSecret. What is wrong with the code ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to get new ConsumerSecret and ConsumerKey, the given keys in tutorial will not work. Sign in [here](http://twitter.com/#!/login?redirect_after_login=/apps/new) and obtain keys for use.